# monthlyReturn and unequal month length

Tags: r, quantmod

I have  300+ companies and need to calculate monthly return for them and later use it as one of the variables in my data set. 
I download prices from Yahoo and calculated monthly return using quantmod package:

```
require(quantmod)    
stockData <- lapply(symbols,function(x) getSymbols(x,auto.assign=FALSE, src='yahoo', from = '2000-01-01'))
    stockDataReturn <- lapply(stockData,function(x) monthlyReturn(Ad(x)))
```

The problem I have is that some companies have different month ends (due to trading halts, etc.) which is reflected in the output list: 2013-12-30 for company AAA and 2013-12-31 for company BBB and the rest of the sample.

When I merge the list using

```
returns <- do.call(merge.xts, stockDataReturn)
```

It creates a separate row for 2013-12-30 with all NAs except for AAA company. 
How can I resolve this? My understanding is that I need to need to stick to month-year format which I need to use as the index before I merge.

Ideally, what I want is that at the monthlyReturn stage, it uses the beginning of the month date rather than end of the month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `lubridate`'s `floor_date` to merge on the same beginning of the month timestamp rather than end of the month timestamp.  Or use `ceiling date` to round to the same end of month timestamp for all securities before merging.

```
library(lubridate)
stockDataReturn <- lapply(stockDataReturn,
                              function(x) {
                                  index(x) <- floor_date(index(x), "month")
                                  # Or if you want to round to end of month change to:
                                  # index(x) <- ceiling_date(index(x), "month")
                                  x
                              })
returns <- do.call(merge, stockDataReturn)
colnames(returns) <- symbols
```

Comment: This is immensely useful. How do we get the last day of month? `ceiling_date(index(x), "month") -1` ?

Comment: @R.S. Yes that can work with date objects in the index vector, but a safer approach, which works with POSIXct objects in the index vector, is  `index(x) <- ceiling_date(index(x), "month") - days(1)`

Comment: @FXQuantTrader  OK. Thanks.

Comment: You can work with `yearmon` index class (`?yearmon`) .